# How to turn a list of lists into seperated lists?

Tags: scheme

If I have a list of lists like '((1 6 7) (4 6 7) (2 6 4)), how can I seperate it into many lists so I can use it in this code:

```
(define func
    (lambda (m) ; (m is the list of lists)
        (map list 'm)))
```

I want to get the first element from every sub list into a new list, then the second element from every list into a new list, all the way to the last element of each list into a new list, then return a list of these new lists.

Right now in the code, m is a list of lists, but is there a way to separate it into it's sub lists, which can be used in the map procedure?

Thanks.

Comment: So the result of function should be '((1 4 2)(6 6 6)(7 7 4))?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Almost there - changing the lambda body to `(apply map list m)` should do the trick.